# How do I save multiple data from responses to use in Gatling / Scala

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

Gatling / Scala n00b here!

I have a Gatling Scala script that creates a new user and the server creates a unique userId each time it's executed. I then get the userId from the response and use it to delete the user associated with the userId.

What I am trying to do now is create 100 users and save those 100 userIds so I can later use those ids to delete the 100 users.

How can I store the 100 userIds to use in another script or scenario or exec so I can delete the users?

This is the script for creating and deleting users by userId:

```scala
class createDeleteUser extends Simulation{

  // protocol
  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://redacted.com")

  var timestamp = Iterator
    .continually {Map("timestamp" -> LocalDateTime.now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd_hhmmss")))}

  var randomName = Iterator
    .continually{Map("random" -> Random.alphanumeric.take(6).mkString)}

  //scenario
  val scn = scenario("Create & Delete User")
    .feed(randomName)
    .feed(timestamp)
    .exec(
      http("Create new user")
        .post("/users")
        .header("content-type", "application/json")
        .body(StringBody(
        """{
          |  "firstName": "${random}",
          |  "lastName": "${timestamp}",
          |  "email": "redacted+${random}@gmail.com",
          |}""".stripMargin)).asJson
      .check(
        status is 200,
        jsonPath("$.userId").saveAs("userId")))
    .pause(1)
    .exec(session => {
      val response = session("userId").as[String]
      println("Response body: \n$response")
      session})
    .pause(1)
    .exec(
      http("Delete user by userId")
        .delete("/users")
        .check(status is 200))

  //setup
  setUp(
    scn.inject(rampUsers(100).during(60))).protocols(httpProtocol)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Scala n00b here!

It might be worth switch to Java or Kotlin (supported since Gatling 3.7) if you're more proficient with them.

> How can I store the 100 userIds to use in another script or scenario or exec so I can delete the users?

Don't do that in another Simulation.

- record the userIds in a ConcurrentHashMap, using an [`exec(function)` block](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#exec)
- perform the deletes in a follow up scenario that would be triggered once the actual one completes, with [`andThen`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/injection/#sequential-scenarios)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this today and let you know how it goes.